# How to to use django createsuperuser --noinput command

Tags: python, django

I'm fairly new to django and python and guess this is a basic question, but if anyone is able to tell me what I'm doing wrong and/or how to correctly struture a non-interactive django createsuperuser command (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser), I'd be really grateful. I would like to use this to create a superuser on a google cloud-run app I have running, and am trying to get this to work locally (on a seperate app created for testing purposes), but can't
seem to. I've found surprisingly little about from quite a bit of googling and browsing Stackoverflow (probably because it's too obvious).

I have a basic django app that is working locally on Ubuntu with a CustomUser model in place. I'm able to create a superuser interactively without a problem. I have DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD/EMAIL/USERNAME defined in my settings.py as detailed below (I know I will need to remove actual values in the future but just want to get it to work first).

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Local
    'accounts',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'

DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD = 'xxx'
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL = 'xxx@email.com'
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME = 'xxx'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators
```

My CustomUser model is as below (but allows interactive creation of a superuser):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

I have tried various permutations of createsuperuser which don't work. The more sensible ones below (I think):

```
./manage.py createsuperuser --noinput --username DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME --email DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL --password DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD
./manage.py createsuperuser --noinput --username USERNAME --email EMAIL --password PASSWORD 
./manage.py createsuperuser --noinput --username DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME --email DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL
./manage.py createsuperuser --noinput --username USERNAME --email EMAIL
./manage.py createsuperuser --noinput, username=DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME, email=DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME, password=DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD
```

Any help/guidance/direction would be gratefully received!

Many thanks

Comment: Add the custom user model to your question `accounts.CustomUser`

Comment: Thank you. Custom user model added above. It's just a placeholder at the moment. Could that be the issue? Just confused why I can create a superuser interactively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command *createsuperuser* can't use you settings.py to read your variables DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD, DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL and DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME.

The command can only read environments variables.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser

You have to set your different environment variable first. Pay attention to the way you are setting your variables if you work with unix, windows or you are using it in a dockerfile.

```
DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL=xxx@email.com
export DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL

DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME=xxx
export DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME

DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=xxx
export DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD
```

And then you can use the following command :

```
./manage.py createsuperuser --noinput --username $DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME --email $DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL --password $DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD
```

There too, you have to look for the way you call environments variables depending on your OS.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful. I ended up hardcoding in the variables, so will change to using this approach.

Comment: Password does not seem to be recognized as parameter.

Comment: flag `--password` does  not exist.

Answer (score 6):

When you export the `DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL` / `DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME` / `DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD` environment variables you can call `manage.py` with just the  `--noinput` parameter:

```bash
$ export DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL=admin@example.com
$ export DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME=admin
$ export DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx

$ ./manage.py createsuperuser --noinput
```

Instead of exporting the variables in your local environment you can also define them in the environment for a single command like so:

```bash
$ DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME=admin DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL=admin@example.com DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=xxxxx ./manage.py createsuperuser --noinput
```